# MOSFETs in series connection

Tags: mosfet

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffP533.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When designing combinational circuits using MOSFETs, it is right to say that if two of them(identical) are in series then their channel length gets doubled but their width remains unchanged?

Edit 1 : Inserted the schematic

Comment: Are you talking about _cascoding_ FETs? It's a little ambiguous when you say two FETs in series.

Comment: Two nmos with their source of 1 tied to the drain of another,  drain 1 is at Vdd and source 2 is at gnd, the gates take input V1 and V2

Comment: @Raven, please add a schematic. Edit your question, and after the editor pops up, note the icon at the top that looks like schematic symbols. Click on that icon and it will pull up a schematic editor.

Comment: And what about the gates? Where are they connected?

Comment: I have added a schematic, hope this helps

Comment: Two mosfets in series don't act like one mosfet with a longer channel. They act like two separate mosfets.

Comment: can you tell me on what basis you are giving this argument?

Comment: okay, I think I got it, when the gate voltages for them will be different, then yes they will behave like individual entities, but what if both inputs are HIGH(Vdd) ?

Comment: The gate-source voltage is a critical parameter for a mosfet. If the gate voltages are the same, but the source voltages are different, then they will not have the same characteristics.

Comment: Okay, I think I get your point

Comment: @Raven: If both gates were high wouldn't you have shoot-through on the two MOSFETs and destroy them?